# Writing HID service with PyBluez

Tags: python, bluetooth, hid, bluez

Need to emulate HID device on Linux using PyBluez.
I have a HID devices (which I'm going to emulate).
`sdptool browse` command shows me that it provides the following service

```
Service Name: HID service
Service RecHandle: 0x10001
Service Class ID List:
  "Human Interface Device" (0x1124)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
    PSM: 17
  "HIDP" (0x0011)
Language Base Attr List:
  code_ISO639: 0x656e
  encoding:    0x6a
  base_offset: 0x100
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Human Interface Device" (0x1124)
    Version: 0x0101
```

So I need to create a service with python equivalent to this.
The problem is that it absolutely ignores `Service class ID list` that I provide.

Here is the code:

```
from bluetooth import *

server_sock=BluetoothSocket(L2CAP)
server_sock.bind(("", 17))
server_sock.listen(1)

uuid = "1f16e7c0-b59b-11e3-95d2-0002a5d5c51b"

advertise_service( server_sock, "PyBluez TEST",
                   service_id = uuid,
                   service_classes = [ HID_CLASS ],
                   profiles = [ HID_PROFILE ])

print("Waiting for connection on L2CAP")

try:
    client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()
    print("Accepted connection from ", client_info)

    while True:
        data = client_sock.recv(1024)
        if len(data) == 0:
                break
        print("received [%s]" % data)
except IOError:
    pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Stopping..."
    stop_advertising(server_sock)
    sys.exit()  

print("disconnected")

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
print("all done")
```

and now I run `sdptool` using another bluetooth adapter and here is what I see

```
Service Name: PyBluez TEST
Service RecHandle: 0x10011
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
    PSM: 17
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Human Interface Device" (0x1124)
    Version: 0x0100
```

**Where is Service Class ID List?**

According to [this](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rudolph/Teaching/Articles/BTBook-march.pdf) book (page 65) it should be there, but it's not.

Here is also HCI configuration

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:17:9A:3F:54:6F  ACL MTU: 1017:8  SCO MTU: 64:0
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:37882 acl:320 sco:0 events:949 errors:0
    TX bytes:41443 acl:352 sco:0 commands:629 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0x8d 0xfe 0x9b 0xf9 0x00 0x80
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'My HID Device'
    Class: 0x6e0100
    Service Classes: Networking, Rendering, Capturing, Audio, Telephony
    Device Class: Computer, Uncategorized
    HCI Version: 2.0 (0x3)  Revision: 0x403d
    LMP Version: 2.0 (0x3)  Subversion: 0x430e
    Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)
```

I would be happy to get any help on this. Books, documentation, examples... anything, that might help with emulation of HID device.

** UPDATE **

Looks like I also have a problems on connection level. My HID host automatically disconnects after pairing.

**Is it generally possible to make my Bluetooth adapter behave like a HID device and how?**

Comment: What if you `print HID_CLASS`? Do you see the value, '1124'?

Comment: Yes. It prints 1124, and it's not actually related to the HID class. I see the same behavior when I set ANY service class ID. SERIAL_PORT_CLASS or anything else. I also tried to run `hciconfig hci0 reset`, but this doesn't help much as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set service class uuid with the `sdptool`:

> ```
> sdptool setseq 0x10011 0x0001 u0x1124
> ```

but it has limited capabilities.

I have found another way to advertise service using [dbus-python](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/) library:

```
import dbus

def advertise_service(sdp_record_xml):
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/"),
                             "org.bluez.Manager")
    adapter_path = manager.FindAdapter(self.device_id)
    service = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", adapter_path),
                             "org.bluez.Service")
    service.AddRecord(sdp_record_xml)
```

And here is an example of the XML SDP record:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<record>
    <attribute id="0x0001">
        <!-- ServiceClassIDList -->
        <sequence>
            <uuid value="00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" />
        </sequence>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0003">
        <!-- ServiceID -->
        <uuid value="00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" />
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0004">
        <!-- ProtocolDescriptorList -->
        <sequence>
            <sequence>
                <uuid value="0x0100" />
            </sequence>
            <sequence>
                <uuid value="0x0003" />
                <uint8 value="0x3" />  <!-- RFCOMM channel -->
            </sequence>
        </sequence>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0005">
        <!-- BrowseGroupList -->
        <sequence>
            <uuid value="0x1002" />
        </sequence>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0100">
        <!-- Service name -->
        <text value="My Service" />
    </attribute>
</record>
```

Comment: how do you edit sap_record.xml or change it programmatically? I'm trying to create virtual bluetooth gamepad on raspberry pi with 30 buttons and 6 axises, how do I write those capabilities to sdp_record?